# How to include class which uses base class

Tags: c++, class, oop

The question is hard to ask but I'll try to explain:
I have a class World that import Class Species, and holds list of Species.
I need to have pointer to class World in class Species, but if I import Class World before declaring Species errors occurs.

Example in pseudo code:

```
import B
Class A
{
list of B
}
```

```
Class B
{
Class A* a
}
```

so I need to import class A to make pointer to it, but when I do Class B is not declared in clas A.

my code:

```
    
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Species
{

protected:
    std::string speciesName;
    int strengh;
    int effort;
    int posX;
    int posY;
    int specieSymbol;

public:
    Species();
    Species(std::string speciesName, int strengh, int effort, int posX, int posY);

    int getPosX();
    int getPosY();

    void setPosX(int x);
    void setPosY(int y);

    int getSpeciesSymbol();

    std::string getSpeciesName();

    virtual void action() = 0;
    virtual void colision() = 0;

    //void setWorld(World* w);
    //World* getWorld();

    ~Species();
};
```

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Species.h"
#include <list>
#include "Board.h"
class World
{
private:
    std::list <Species*> species;
    Board* board;

public:
    World(Board *board);

    void addSpecies(Species* s);
    
    void printSpecies();

    void printWorld();

    void Update();
    
    ~World();
};
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes) help answer your question?

Comment: I think it's what I mean, but I have hard time understanding it, but will keep on trying.